# Not able to access Yarn logs running on a docker container cluster from browser

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have spark hadoop cluster running on docker containers. When I submit spark command using Yarn and try to see logs from browser I am not able see because worker container name is not accessible from the browser. I have to manually change URL to point to HostIP instead of worker container hostname to access logs. Is there anyway I can map yarn logs to Host server IP so that I can access from browser.

I tried giving worker hostname as server hostname so that I can access logs using server host name but spark submit not working because not able to find worker on the host server. Tried assigning yarn.nodemanager.webapp.https.address to host serverv IP but spark submit itself not working.
Basically from Image I want logs URL to be pointed to Hostserver IP so that it can be accessible.
[image]